# unity: HTTP PUT problemas

Tags: webservice, unity3d, unity, unity2d

Soy nuevo en unity pero consegui hacer los metodos http get, post , delete. Mi problema ocurre en el PUT, logro hacer bien la llamada al servidor , sin embargo este no hace nada, y cambia todo a null, supongo que es un error en la variable "json" pero no consigo arreglarlo, si hago el metodo put con otras herramientas como lo es Postman todo va perfecto

[documentacionUnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/es/current/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html)

```
public void botonActualizar(){
     StartCoroutine(Upload());
}

[System.Serializable]
public class myClase
{
    public string nombre;
    public string descripcion;
}
public IEnumerator Upload()
{

    string url = "http://localhost:3001/v1/0001";
    myClase myObject = new myClase();
    myObject.nombre = "nombre";
    myObject.descripcion = "ejemplo";
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(myObject);

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Put(url, json);
    yield return www.Send();

    if (www.isError)
    {
        Debug.Log(www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("upload complete!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Deberías probar esta librería Open Source para hacer requests http (Basada en promesas) https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a definir la petición de la siguiente forma:

```
           UnityWebRequest request = new UnityWebRequest(url, "PUT");

            if (jsonData != null)
            {
                byte[] bodyRaw = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
                request.uploadHandler = new UploadHandlerRaw(bodyRaw);
            }

            request.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
            request.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```